Defining Bind Paths and Mounts in Def Files
I am using Apptainer to containerize a JupyterLab server.
I want my container to bind to the home directory and a few other settings-related directories.
I picked up this project from a coworker, and they've set up the binding process through a StartServer.sh script. This script also handles other startup businesses. I understand having such a script, but I would like to minimize its complexity and keep as much of the container's setup and configuration in def files.
However, it appears that apptainer only lets you set up bind paths through the apptainer.conf, or through command arguments under --bind and --mount. I would much prefer setting this up in the def file. I have a layered system of def files to build an image and would like the last one to handle the final setup: binding, server-related scripts, run scripts...
This is very surprising to me, are there other ways to systematically configure a container's bind paths other than the apptainer configuration file? How do you handle your containers and do you have any tips to keep containers and their configurations/building steps as tightly packaged as possible, so other collaborators spend a minimal amount of time figuring out how it all comes together?
